# can't get sum(column) with left join on row ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table that looks like below.

```
ID : type : stat
----------------
1  : t1   :  0
2  : t2   :  0
3  : t3   :  1
```

I want to create another temp table to look like

```
ID : type : stat : qty
----------------------
1  : t1   :  0   : 10
2  : t2   :  0   : 20
3  : t3   :  1   : 30
```

however the qty comes from another table that has multiple rows. ex

```
ID : junk : junk : qty
----------------------
1  : t1   :  0   :  5
1  : t2   :  0   :  5
2  : t3   :  1   : 15
3  : t1   :  0   :  5
3  : t2   :  0   : 20
3  : t3   :  1   : 10
```

here is my current query to get the first table.

```sql
select table1.ID, table1.type, table1.stat  
into #tempTable1
from table1
where start_date >= dateADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, getdate()), -1)  --sunday
and start_date <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 5) --saturday
```

here is my current query attempt to combine them which is not working but I don't know how to solve it.

```
select #tempTable1.id, #tempTable1.type, #tempTable1.stat, sum(table2.value) as 'qty' 
into #tempTable1
from #tempTable2
left join table2
on #tempTable1.id = table2.id
```

this gives me the error

```
" Column '#temptable.type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. "
```

I have tried to use group by using ID, type, stat as well.

please ignore the lowercase vs upper case, it is correct in my actual sql query.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using temporary tables.  A `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` should do what you want:

```
select t1.ID, t1.type, t1.stat, sum(t2.qty) as qty
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.start_date >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), -1) and --sunday
      t1.start_date <= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 5) --saturday 
group by t1.ID, t1.type, t1.stat;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and to answer your question. I did not know I could do that. I don't really write SQL.